# text alignment with textplot() (PerformanceAnalytics package)

Tags: r

I would like to align text in a table using textplot(). Here's my code:

```
liste<-list(1,2)
tabindex<-data.frame(liste)
colnames(tabindex)<-c("Abreviation","Definition")
tabindex[1,]<-c("SAI : ","Strategy AI : stock's weight depending on AI")
tabindex<-rbind(tabindex,"")
tabindex[2,]<-c("SBH : ","Strategy BH : constant stock's weight")
textplot(tabindex,hadj=0,cex=0.8)
```

How can I align a text properly (in any direction) in each column?

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your textplot call, is this what you want?

```
textplot(tabindex, halign="left", valign="center", cmar = 0.5, cex=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: The text is aligned to the right. How can I align it to the left in each column, including the column names? Thanks